# How to Remove Readonly property in selenium using python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
 ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/fieldset[2]/table/tbody/tr[15]/td[3]/input')
 driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('readonly')", ele)
```

This is My python script.

[image]

Comment: try to access input by tagname

Comment: Or else by id.Your xpath is long